# IE10 Issue with Scrollbar on Div

Tags: css, html, scrollbar, overflow, internet-explorer-10

I am using a scrollbar on a div and it appears to be having a rendering issue in IE10.

When you scroll the div all the way to the bottom, then back to top, the top content is missing.

Do you know if there is a solution for IE10?

Link:
http://landpros.com/propsearch.php

Here is the CSS on the div:

```
.prop-search-content-wrapper{
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 980px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what's missing. I don't notice anything missing on mine.

Comment: Here is what it looks like broken:
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JqYhq.png

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work out like I wanted, but the link will show an image. Does that work?

Comment: That link works fine for me in IE10, I can scroll to the bottom and back up and the content is still there. Are you doing something else to cause it? Did it work on IE9? Does it work in another browser (Chrome, Firefox)?

Comment: So odd. I see it when I scroll to the bottom of the "div with the scroll bar" and then all the way to the bottom of the page (using page scroll bar). Then scroll back to the top "div with the scroll bar". 

It's almost like the two scrollbars working together might be the issue.

Looks good in all other browsers I've checked except IE10.

Comment: Have you tried with another IE10 browser?

Answer (score 3):

I did manage to reproduce this - to see the cause of the issue (I think) turn off the `overflow-x: hidden` directive. If the content is missing it will come back and you will get a vertical scroll bar. Something is going on that is causing IE10 to think it needs to hide that whole top row(s).

The fix should be to readjust your widths of any content of the containing div with class `content-wrapper` to match the parent and never need `overflow-x: hidden;` in the first place.

*Note: I struggled to consistently reproduce.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem with my IE 11 emulating IE 10 with the developer tools. But I agree with Matthew, that it is most probably caused by the `overflow-x: hidden` setting.

You can easily avoid it!

Have a look at your foundation.css file (at line 233 and 235):

```
.row .row { width: auto; max-width: none; min-width: 0; margin: 0 -10px; }
```

Beside the fact that the rule exists twice, your "trouble" arises from the negative left and right margins. You dont need them, so just remove them!

By doing so, there is no more need for the `overflow-x: hidden` setting.
BTW: Why do you set the `max-width` to `none`, instead of `100%`, if you don't want an element to horizontally overflow its parent?

So please try it and let us know, if this fixes (avoids) your problem - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you try with -ms-overflow-style property?

-ms-overflow-style: auto | none | scrollbar | -ms-autohiding-scrollbar

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771902(v=vs.85).aspx